# Querying XML data in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database that has a table `Parameters_XML` with columns.

```
id, application, parameter_nr flag, value
```

The `parameter_nr` is for example 1 and the value for that parameter is the following:

```
<Root>
  <Row>
    <Item id="341" flags="1">
      <Str>2</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="342" flags="1">
      <Str>10</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2196" flags="1">
      <Str>7REPJ1</Str>
    </Item>
  </Row>
</Root>
```

I need to retrieve the values for all the applications where the item is 341, 342 and 2196.

Eg: for the application 1 the value for the item 341 is 2 and so on.

I have written the following query:

```
SELECT cast (value as XML).value('data(/Root/Row/Item[@id="431"],')
FROM Parameters_Xml x
WHERE parameter_nr = 1
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   The value function requires 2 argument(s).

Why my query is not valid?

Comment: down voters should leave comment which is more helpful for improve Q quality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try someting like this:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(x.Value AS XML).value('(/Root/Row/Item[@id="341"]/Str)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
FROM dbo.Parameters_Xml x
WHERE parameter_nr = 1
```

You're telling SQL Server to go find the `<Item>` node (under `<Root> / <Row>`) with and `id=341` (that what I'm assuming - your value in the question doesn't even exist) and then get the first `<Str>` node under `<Item>` and return that value

Also: why do you need `CAST(x.Value as XML)` - if that column contains only XML - why isn't it **defined** with datatype `XML` to begin with? If you have this, you don't need any `CAST` ...

Comment: You just saved my life! Thank you so so much!

Comment: Pls help me again and tell me the path to the item 1179 from this XML:
<Root>
  <Row>
        <Item id="1344" flags="257">
      <Row>
        <Item id="1179" flags="257">
          <Str>Gall Studio Design SRL</Str>
        </Item>
        <Item id="1421" flags="257">
          <Str>22204869</Str>
        </Item>
I’m writing the following query: SELECT CAST(x.Value AS XML).value('(/Root/Row/Item[@id="1344"/Row/Item[@id="1179"])[1]','nvarchar(100)')
FROM Parameters_Xml x
WHERE paramameter_nr = 1 
But i get the following error: XQuery [value()]: Syntax error near ')', expected ']'.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @str XML;
SET @str = '<Root>
  <Row>
    <Item id="341" flags="1">
      <Str>2</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="342" flags="1">
      <Str>10</Str>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2196" flags="1">
      <Str>7REPJ1</Str>
    </Item>
  </Row>
</Root>'

-- if you want specific values then
SELECT 
 xmlData.Col.value('@id','varchar(max)') Item
,xmlData.Col.value('(Str/text())[1]','varchar(max)') Value
FROM @str.nodes('//Root/Row/Item') xmlData(Col)
where xmlData.Col.value('@id','varchar(max)') = 342

--if you want all values then
SELECT 
 xmlData.Col.value('@id','varchar(max)') Item
,xmlData.Col.value('(Str/text())[1]','varchar(max)') Value
FROM @str.nodes('//Root/Row/Item') xmlData(Col)
--where xmlData.Col.value('@id','varchar(max)') = 342
```

**Edit After Comment**If i query my db: select * from parameters_xml where parameter_nr = 1 i will receive over 10000 rows, each row is like the following: Id app param value 1 1 1 11 I need for all the 10000 apps to retrieve the item id and the value from the XML value - like you did for my eg.

```
 -- declare temp table
declare @temp table
    (val xml)
    insert into @temp values ('<Root>
      <Row>
        <Item id="341" flags="1">
          <Str>2</Str>
        </Item>
        <Item id="342" flags="1">
          <Str>10</Str>
        </Item>
        <Item id="2196" flags="1">
          <Str>7REPJ1</Str>
        </Item>
      </Row>
    </Root>')
    insert into @temp values ('<Root>
      <Row>
        <Item id="3411" flags="1">
          <Str>21</Str>
        </Item>
        <Item id="3421" flags="1">
          <Str>101</Str>
        </Item>
        <Item id="21961" flags="1">
          <Str>7REPJ11</Str>
        </Item>
      </Row>
    </Root>')
-- QUERY
     SELECT 
         xmlData.Col.value('@id','varchar(max)') Item
        ,xmlData.Col.value('(Str/text())[1]','varchar(max)') Value
        FROM @temp AS T
        outer apply T.val.nodes('/Root/Row/Item') as xmlData(Col)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, it it excelent! If you could help me with a general select for all the applications, that would be very kind of you. My DataBase has over 10000 values like this and I need to select all of them for all my applications and most of them have much more values in the XML than the eg.

Comment: @RalucaIoana above answer giving us all the values of XML

Comment: I understand that, but it give us all the values from that XML, if I select all from the table parameters_XML, i have over 10000 row, each row containig it's own XML value. I need a query that returns me all the values for all the 10000, each row having it's own XML value.

Comment: @RalucaIoana Sorry i didn't get you what you want to achive

Comment: If i query my db: select * from parameters_xml where parameter_nr = 1 i will receive over 10000 rows, each row is like the following: 
Id app param value
1 1 1 <Root><Row><Item id="341" flags="1"><Str>1</Str></Item><Item id="342" flags="1"><Str>1</Str></Item></Row></Root> 
I need for all the 10000 apps to retrieve the item id and the value from the XML value - like you did for my eg.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> select cast (value as
>   XML).value('data(/Root/Row/Item[@id="431"]','nvarchar(max)')

data type is 2nd parameter.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! i have a new error now:Msg 2217, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
XQuery [value()]: ',' or ')' expected